# AngularFire can't save object

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to save an object to Firebase. I can read the object and it's properties ok but can't save it. The error callback results -> Error: Invalid record; could determine key for undefined.

```
                var ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/myObjects/" + objectKey)
            var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);

            obj.$loaded().then(function () {

                console.log("Some property -> " + obj.testProperty); 

                obj.testProperty= "someValue";

                obj.$save().then(function (ref) {
                    console.log("Saved !");

                }, function (error) {
                    console.log("Error:", error);
                });

            });
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Regards

Comment: just to be clear, you see the correct value in the console log? console.log("Some property -> " + obj.testProperty);  that shows you the value you were expecting?

Comment: Changed that line to console.log("This is the object -> " + JSON.stringfy(obj)) and at the console I have -> 
[{"$value":1,"$id":"codigoDoCliente","$priority":null},{"$value":"A person name","$id":"criadoPor","$priority":null},{"$value":"20160225","$id":"dataDaOcorrencia","$priority":null},{"$value":"Some info...","$id":"descricaoDaOcorrencia","$priority":null},{"$value":4,"$id":"produtoAssociado","$priority":null},{"$value":1,"$id":"tipoDeOcorrencia","$priority":null}] .

Comment: Please don't add code to comments, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35638033/edit) your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first get the array index and then save some property.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/myObjects/");
    var obj = $firebaseArray(ref);
    var index = obj.$indexFor(objectKey)
    obj.$loaded().then(function () {

        console.log("Some property -> " + obj.testProperty); 

        obj[index].testProperty= "someValue";

        obj.$save(index).then(function (ref) {
            console.log("Saved !");

        }, function (error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$save doesn't automatically generate a key so is it possible you have a duplicate objectKey already stored.

Typically we store all our data under a unique identifier, like the user id or random hash, to avoid collisions.  Or instead you can use the $add and Firebase will automatically generate a unique key and store it under that location.
firebaseURL/Profiles/unique id/object

Comment: The object that I'm trying to save is not a new object, it is being edited from a previous saved array at server.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. Mine was caused by having an undefined function parameter. I accidentally included the parameter from another service I copied and pasted without adding that service as a dependency. 
e.g.:

```
angular
  .module('appTasks', [])
  .factory('tasks', [
    '$firebaseObject',
    '$firebaseArray',
    function(users, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) { ...my service code... },]);
```

That `users` parameter was meant to come from a dependency I hadn't included in the `.module` dependency array `[]`, so it was undefined and threw off my entire service, which gave me that error: "Error: Invalid record; could determine key for undefined."

I'm a bit of a newb, so anyone feel free to let me know if I could describe it better a certain way. ;)